# Finding issues when loading data to shopping cart adapter

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview, shopping-cart

I was following this tutorial to achieve my shopping cart in my android application. http://www.androiddom.com/2011/02/android-shopping-cart-tutorial.html

when i run the application cart shows null. when I add items to the cart i can see that there are items in the cart by debugging the shopping cart activity. mCartList send the product ID to the shoppingcartactivity from ShoppingCartHelper. setQuantity method in ShoppingCartHelper has the values for the products added to the cart (description, price and the quantity). Im finding it hard how to load the data to the adapter shown in the shoppingcartactivity.
How can i pass the values to the shoppingcartactivity from ShoppingCartHelper?
Any help would be appreciated.

ShoppingCartHelper

```
public static final String PRODUCT_INDEX = "PRODUCT_INDEX";

private static Map<Product, ShoppingCartEntry> cartMap = new HashMap<Product, ShoppingCartEntry>();


public static void setQuantity(Product product, int quantity) {
    // Get the current cart entry
    ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

    // If the quantity is zero or less, remove the products
    if (quantity <= 0) {
        if (curEntry != null)
            removeProduct(product);
        return;
    }

    // If a current cart entry doesn't exist, create one
    if (curEntry == null) {
        curEntry = new ShoppingCartEntry(product, quantity);
        cartMap.put(product, curEntry);
        return;
    }

    // Update the quantity
    curEntry.setQuantity(quantity);
}

public static int getProductQuantity(Product product) {
    // Get the current cart entry
    ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

    if (curEntry != null)
        return curEntry.getQuantity();

    return 0;
}

public static void removeProduct(Product product) {
    cartMap.remove(product);
}

public static List<Product> getCartList() {
    List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
    for (Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
        cartList.add(p);
    }

    return cartList;
}
```

}

ShoppingCartActivity

```
     public class ShoppingCartActivity extends Activity {

            private ProductAdapter mProductAdapter;
            private List<Product> mCartList;

            ExpandableListView expListView;
            List<String> listDataHeader;
            List<String> listDataHeaderPrice;
            List<String> listDataHeaderQty;
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
            private ExpandableListView mExpandableList;

            String description;
            String price;
            String quantity;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.cart_activity);

                mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();

                // Make sure to clear the selections
                for (int i = 0; i < mCartList.size(); i++) {
                    mCartList.get(i).selected = false;
                }

                // get the listview
                expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

                // preparing list data
                prepareListData();

                mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, listDataHeader,
                        listDataHeaderPrice, listDataHeaderQty, listDataChild);

                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

           }
private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataHeaderPrice = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataHeaderQty = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add(description);
        listDataHeaderPrice.add(price);
        listDataHeaderQty.add(quantity);

}
```

productadapter

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader;
    private List<String> _listDataHeaderQty;
    private List<String> _listDataHeaderPrice; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            List<String> listDataHeaderPrice, List<String> listDataHeaderQty,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataHeaderPrice = listDataHeaderPrice;
        this._listDataHeaderQty = listDataHeaderQty;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_group, null);

            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            holder.tvHeaderPrice = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lbl_unitprice);
            holder.tvHeaderQty = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lbl_qty);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvHeader.setText(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
        holder.tvHeaderPrice.setText(_listDataHeaderPrice.get(groupPosition));
        holder.tvHeaderQty.setText(_listDataHeaderQty.get(groupPosition));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvHeader;
        private TextView tvHeaderPrice;
        private TextView tvHeaderQty;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post ProductAdapter code?

Comment: @EagleEye i have updated the question, check it plz

Comment: mCartList is not null in activty class right? its returning with values right? If so, problem is in adapter class

Comment: mCartList is returning the product Code(number), not the values. so im finding it difficult how to get the values which belongs to the product code. i think problem is in where i load the items to the adapter

Comment: Yes. You are loading a empty hashmap to the adapter.

Comment: how can i overcome this, im bit confused at the moment